# Is there a way to declare an abstract class or interface to enforce implementing class it initialise that field?

Tags: java, c#

Whether C# or Java, is it anyway to enforce the class define "EXAMPLE" field?

```
public interface IWorkflow{
    public static final String EXAMPLE;// interface field 
    public void reject();
}

// and implement class
public class AbstWorkflow implements IWorkflow
{
    public static final String EXAMPLE = "ABCD"; /*MUST HAVE*/
    public void reject(){}
...
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a Constructor interface?

Comment: Please ask a question about one language only, asking a question about two languages is effectively asking two questions.

Comment: Related: In c# as of its 9.0 specification they introduced the [init accessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, make it abstract (in C#)

```
public abstract class WorkflowBase{
    public static abstract String EXAMPLE {set;get;}
    public void reject();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also `static abstract String EXAMPLE {get;init;}` because OP in fact mentions initialization and in c# 9.0 [they introduced the accessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init). Actually your code only makes sure it is implemented, but not initialized.

Comment: Though that's a property, not a field.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yeah, but I guessed the question is looking for properties